# How to set custom gas price?

Tags: gas

Absurd Gas Prices From the BAT Token Creation Period

```
118 GWEI * 200000 == 0.0236 ETH == $6.13 USD
7590 GWEI * 200000 == 1.518 ETH == $394.68 USD
58000 GWEI * 200000 == 11.6 ETH == $3,016 USD
```

How to set custom gas price? No matter what way, I can't set gas price more than 60GWEI on MyEtherWallet.

Comment: If you do not want to deploy your own node, you can choose another wallet that can let you set the gas price, or ask the MEW developers with a github issue.

Answer (score 2):

MyEtherWallet prevents you from setting a gas price higher than 60 Gwei to stop people from accidentally submitting transactions with ridiculously high gas prices.

If you want to submit a gas price higher than that you should set up your own node, and sign your own transactions.

In the time it takes you to learn how to do all that, you will also realise it is completely unnecessary :)